# How to pass UTC date from client to mongo db c# driver and filter?

Tags: c#, mongodb, datetime, mongodb-.net-driver, utc

Is there anyway to prevent the mongodb c# driver from converting any date passed in a filter query to UTC but instead accept the date as UTC?

I am using .net core 2.1 with some telerik controls to display a grid. Inside of the header of the grid I have a filter control to filter a date range.

[image]

Inside the client event before filtering I am capturing the date and converting it to utc:

```
function onGridFilter(e) {
        // check if it is a date field
        if (e.filter && e.field === "created"){
            convertDateToUTC(e.filter);
        }
    }

    function convertDateToUTC(filter) {
        var filters = filter.filters;
        for (var i = 0; i < filters.length; i++) {
            if (filters[i].field === "created") {
                var date = filters[i].value;
                var isoDate = new Date(date.getUTCFullYear(), date.getUTCMonth(), date.getUTCDate(), date.getUTCHours(), date.getUTCMinutes(), date.getUTCSeconds());                    
                filter.filters[i].value = isoDate;
            }
        }
    }
```

In the API call I am converting the UTC date to the local time of the server like so (this API is a kubernetes microservice and can have a different time zone depending on where it is deployed):

```
// Update the dates to server times for filtering, mongo will accept dates and convert to UTC based on the server location
        foreach (var f in this.Filters)
        {
            if (f.ConvertedValue.GetType() == typeof(DateTime))
            {
                DateTime dt = (DateTime)f.Value;
                f.Value = dt.ToLocalTime();
            }
        }
```

Using the telerik filter (DataSourceRequest object) and the mongodb c# driver (linq to mongo) I am creating a mongo query to filter the records in the mongo database.

```
 public DataSourceResult GetCollectionQuery(string organizationId, DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        IMongoCollection<Case> casesCollection = _db.GetCollection<Case>(_collection);
        IMongoCollection<Person> personCollection = _db.GetCollection<Person>(_personCollection);
        IQueryable<CaseListViewModel> query;

        // Setup full results query
        query = (from c in casesCollection.AsQueryable()
                 where c.OrganizationId == organizationId
                 join p in personCollection.AsQueryable() on c.ClientId equals p.Id into p
                 from person in p.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 select new CaseListViewModel()
                 {
                     Id = c.Id,
                     DisplayName = person != null ? person.LastName + ", " + person.FirstName : string.Empty,
                     OrganizationCaseId = c.OrganizationCaseId,
                     ServiceName = c.ServiceName,
                     ClientType = c.ClientType,
                     Addresses = c.ClientTypeValue == ClientTypeValue.Person ? person.Addresses != null ?
                                    person.Addresses.Where(o => !o.End.HasValue).Select(o => o.AddressLine1) : null : null,
                     Worker = string.Empty, //c.Assignments,
                     Created = c.Created,
                     Status = c.Status,
                     OrganizationGeography = person != null ? person.OrganizationGeography != null ? person.OrganizationGeography.Name : string.Empty : string.Empty
                 });

        // Filter/Sort/Page results
        return query.ToDataSourceResult(request);
    }
```

The reason I am converting the client to UTC, UTC to server then passing that date to the mongo query is because the client and server can be in different time zones.

This seems like it is a lot of unnecessary work to filter the date on the grid. Currently this solution does work, however I am looking for an alternative on the mongodb c# driver side. I want the mongodb query to read all dates AS UTC instead of converting the dates retrieved to UTC.

I know there is a way to tell a property that it is being saved as utc with the BsonDateTimeOptions DateTimeKind:

```
[BsonElement(elementName: "created")]
[BsonDateTimeOptions(Kind = DateTimeKind.Utc)]
public DateTime Created { get; set; }
```

Is there something similar for queries?

***Update:***
The solution was to specify what the DateTimeKind was for the date being filtered.

```
foreach (var f in this.Filters)
        {
            if (f.ConvertedValue.GetType() == typeof(DateTime))
            {
                DateTime dt = (DateTime)f.Value;
                dt = DateTime.SpecifyKind(dt, DateTimeKind.Utc);
                f.Value = dt;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try to use `DateTime.SpecifyKind` for your date like this:

```
query = (from c in casesCollection.AsQueryable()
...
select new CaseListViewModel()
{
    ...
    Created = DateTime.SpecifyKind(c.Created, DateTimeKind.Utc)
}
```

In this case mongodb driver should interpret the date as already in utc, so it won't perform conversion.

Comment: This got me extremely close to the answer. I had to do what you specified when setting up the filter. 
`foreach (var f in this.Filters)
            {
                if (f.ConvertedValue.GetType() == typeof(DateTime))
                {
                    DateTime dt = (DateTime)f.Value;
                    dt = DateTime.SpecifyKind(dt, DateTimeKind.Utc);
                    f.Value = dt;
                }
            }` Not sure how to format this any better in a comment. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but there are a few things I see in your code:

- In your client-side code, you have:

  ```javascript
  var isoDate = new Date(date.getUTCFullYear(), date.getUTCMonth(), date.getUTCDate(), date.getUTCHours(), date.getUTCMinutes(), date.getUTCSeconds());
  ```

  This is a common anti-pattern, and you should not ever do that.  The `Date` object's parameters expect values in local time, and you are passing values that are in UTC.  Doing this is basically the same as adding the amount of the local time zone's UTC offset.  In other words, it does not *convert* the object to a different time zone, it simply picks a different moment in time.

  What you probably want to do instead is `date.toISOString()`.  This will emit a UTC-based string in ISO 8601 format that is appropriate to send to the server.
- In your server-side code, you have:

  ```csharp
  f.Value = dt.ToLocalTime();
  ```

  This will convert to the *server's* local time zone.  In the vast majority of cases, you should avoid writing code that depends on the server's time zone setting.  Instead, keep the input time in UTC as it was given to you.  Store using UTC, query using UTC, and return UTC-based responses.  In your client-side code that receives the response, convert back to local time using the `Date` object, or a library.

Also, in your `GetCollectionQuery`, I don't see anything related to date or time at all, so I'm not sure how that relates to your question.

Comment: My question is can I prevent mongo from converting a date by default to a UTC date when querying?

Comment: I want to remove the conversion to the servers local time however I can't. Mongo would read the date time provided by the client as the servers local time and then add the offset when converting to mongo's UTC date. Example: If the client was in Hawaii (-10) and the user selected the date time "01/01/2018 04:10 AM" I would convert that to UTC "01/01/2018 02:10 PM". The server (lets say EST (-5)) would then take that time and pass it to mongo as is. Mongo would then convert it to "01/01/2018 07:10 PM" before filtering. Which is the incorrect date time.

Comment: `return query.ToDataSourceResult(request);` Is used to build the mongo filter query. This is a Telerik feature, the query is built behind the scenes.

Comment: There's nothing in MongoDB that demands values be converted in the way you describe.  It can do so, but it depends greatly on exactly how the values are passed, and which objects are being used.  I don't see any of that here, so it's difficult to help you.  Can you show the actual query being sent to MongoDB somehow?

Comment: The problem was that when the UTC date was being passed to mongo in the generated query by default the filter was setup as a unspecified DateTimeKind. The above answer gave me more of what I was looking for, but this did help me think in more depth about why the date was being converted like it was by mongo. Thank you